# boost discrete uniform distribution

Tags: c++, boost, statistics, uniform-distribution

I have a variety of distributions from which I draw samples, pdf and cdf. For polymorphic reasons I am using a uniform_distribution instead of uniform_int_distribution.

The following returns me a floating value between 10 and 20 instead of integral values:

```
 typedef uniform_distribution<double,
                policy<discrete_quantile<integer_round_outwards>>> uniform_round_outwards;

 uniform_round_outwards  _uniformObject(10,20);

 x = quantile(_uniformObject, p);
```

Is the policy being applied at all?

Comment: The answer by sehe suggests there is no discrete uniform distribution. But if you have a continuous uniform distribution between integral limits, then floor(x) where x is sampled from the continuous distribution has a uniform discrete distribution over the integers from the lower limit to the greater minus 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For polymorphic reasons I am using a `uniform_distribution` instead of `uniform_int_distribution`.

The Math library doesn't have a `uniform_int_distribution`, making that a weird statement.

> The following returns me a floating value between 10 and 20 instead of integral values:

That distribution is a continuous distribution. [The docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/uniform_dist.html) only fleetingly refer to Wikipedia to say "There is also a discrete uniform distribution.", but they fail to explicitly state whether or not such a thing is implemented.

Looking at the source shows that the policy is not being used:

```
  template <class RealType, class Policy>
  inline RealType quantile(const uniform_distribution<RealType, Policy>& dist, const RealType& p)
  {
    RealType lower = dist.lower();
    RealType upper = dist.upper();
    RealType result = 0; // of checks
    if(false == detail::check_uniform("boost::math::quantile(const uniform_distribution<%1%>&, %1%)",lower, upper, &result, Policy()))
    {
      return result;
    }
    if(false == detail::check_probability("boost::math::quantile(const uniform_distribution<%1%>&, %1%)", p, &result, Policy()))
    {
      return result;
    }
    if(p == 0)
    {
      return lower;
    }
    if(p == 1)
    {
      return upper;
    }
    return p * (upper - lower) + lower;
  }
```

My conclusion is that the discrete uniform distribution is not implemented in this class.